# Neo4J bolt connector not working

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to start Neo4J embedded db (3.2.0) and then access this db from another jvm process via bolt driver (1.4.4). Although my code below do print sysouts indicating that db has started,

```
    System.out.println("Starting Neo embedded database at " + databaseFile);
    BoltConnector bolt = new BoltConnector("key");
    service = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(databaseFile))
            .setConfig(bolt.enabled, "true").setConfig(bolt.type, "BOLT")
            .setConfig(bolt.encryption_level, "DISABLED").newGraphDatabase();
    System.out.println("Started Neo embedded database");
```

my another jvm process running on same machine trying to query db via bolt driver fails with below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to localhost:7687, ensure the database is running and that there is a working network connection to it.
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:132)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.startSocketClient(SocketConnection.java:92)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:67)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnector.createConnection(SocketConnector.java:77)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:50)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:216)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool$ConnectionSupplier.get(SocketConnectionPool.java:198)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.acquire(BlockingPooledConnectionQueue.java:96)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SocketConnectionPool.java:149)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.SocketConnectionPool.acquire(SocketConnectionPool.java:76)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DirectConnectionProvider.acquireConnection(DirectConnectionProvider.java:47)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DirectConnectionProvider.verifyConnectivity(DirectConnectionProvider.java:67)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DirectConnectionProvider.<init>(DirectConnectionProvider.java:41)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.createDirectDriver(DriverFactory.java:109)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:93)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.DriverFactory.newInstance(DriverFactory.java:67)
at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:135)
at org.neo4j.driver.v1.GraphDatabase.driver(GraphDatabase.java:117)
at 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ChannelFactory.connect(ChannelFactory.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ChannelFactory.create(ChannelFactory.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.start(SocketClient.java:126)
    ... 20 more
```

running netstat on windows doesn't show any process listening to port 7687, can someone please help.